# Keeping the SELECTED Div's Open in the all the webpages

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, facebook

Keeping Facebook and google+ in mind....
As you have seen there are chat windows opened at bottom of the screen(which u opened).
When you go to a different page

Now you click on someone's profile-> The Chat window opened in the previous page was still found to be opened , instead of opening it again from the Chat List

I want a simmilar kind of functionality for my school social network.

What i am doing is calling `require_once('chatlist.php')` at start of each page to show the `chatList` at the bottom of my screen.And users click the people in chatlist to open the respective persons's chat window.
But every time a new page is clicked within the website. The chat window we were currently chatting to is gone! So this is quite irritating.
How can i prevent this type of thing from happening.

**chatlist.php**

```
<div class"chatlist">
<?php
    #$data contains all people's data from users table
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)){
      echo '<li class="chatli" data-id="'.$row['user_id'].'">';  //onclick this opens the respective users chat-window
      echo $row['name'];
      echo '</li>';
    }
?>
</div>
```

Comment: will have to store state using javascript either in cookie, localStorage or send ajax request to server and store there. Alternatively change site to ajax driven single page application

Comment: its huge and cant be done single page! cookkie or localstorage  can be option but can u explain ? @charlietfl

Comment: simplest case...on open store state with 2 variables openState and id. When page loads react to those conditions with your script. If user closes chat change openState and store

Comment: ok but how to do em in localStorage ? When `onlick` `li.chatli` i am able to store the data using `localStorage.setItem()`. When loading a different page i will fetch the data using `localStorage.getItem()` But how to transfer them in a PHP variable without redirecting to a different page to process em ? @charlietfl

Comment: use cookie or ajax, have no idea how your chat system is initialized. I assume it already uses javascript connection to server somehow if it is real time chat

Comment: ok thanks for your advice @charlietfl i will look into this without troubling you anymore